# Harmonize geometry of different shapefiles (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, geometry, snapping

I have got to harmonize the geometry of a big amount of shapefiles in QGIS [image: inequality of the shapefiles]

The files are actually very big. So it would be a lot of work to do it manually. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: What do you mean by "harmonize"? Your map doesn't really help.

Comment: ann chi - it looks like you're probably asking about how to make one set of polygons match another set, but as Spacedman says your question isn't clear enough to answer. And you probably don't mean 'shapefiles' but 'polygons' (i.e. shapes). Shapefile is a type of file (like 'docx' is a type of file opened with MS Word for example - 'shapefile' is a type of file opened with a GIS application). OR if you do really mean lots of shapefiles - are you meaning that each of the polygons shown on your map is in a different file? And when you say 'big' do you mean that the polygons have many points?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Snap Geometries to Layer` tool, which you can find in the Processing Toolbox.

> **Snap geometries to layer**
>
> This algorithm snaps the geometries in a layer. Snapping can be done either to the geometries from another layer, or to geometries within the same layer.
> A tolerance is specified in layer units to control how close vertices need to be to the reference layer geometries before they are snapped.
> Snapping occurs to both nodes and edges. Depending on the snapping behavior, either nodes or edges will be preferred.
> Vertices will be inserted or removed as required to make the geometries match the reference geometries.